# Get more info from a list of objects using Koala to access Facebook Graph API on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

After instantiating a connection to the Graph API, I can do this:

```
@graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

This returns a list of friends containing their name and id.

If I wanted more info from these friends, I can do:

```
@graph.get_connections("me", "friends").each do |f|
    fdetails = get_object(f['id'])
    # do stuff
end
```

But this way I will have to make as many requests to the Graph API as the number of friends!

Is there something that would give me the fields I want from each user from the initial call?

In short, how do I do this?

```
@graph.get_connections("me", "friends", :fields => "image,bio")
```

Comment: I just realized I can use `@graph.get_objects` with a list of ids. But this is still 2 queries, is it possible to make it only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in your controller :

```
 graph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:token])
          user = graph.get_object("me")
          @friends = graph.get_connections(user["id"], "friends?fields=id,name,link")
session[:token] : contain my token
```

and in your view for example :

```
    <% @friends.each do |f| %>
<%= link_to f["name"], f["link"], :target => '_blank'%>
```